# Create and manage remote services to different devices

Tags: php, ajax, session, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using a cross domain and uses php server to get user info when logging in.  In my running website I use php code and when the user login I added this code

```
session_start();
```

Then just declare the user info when successfully logged in like:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['user_email'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['user_name'];
```

And then I use that session `$user['user_id'];` in every user requests.

How to implement a session when the user logged on Hybrid app? Is it the same on how my running website works? Do I just need to add session code on the ajax request? Any idea?

Comment: It is better if you can implement it as an API, with access tokens. Each ap will get a unique access token and it will be provided to you every time the app is sending a request to you.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha, so it is possible to implement it using the server side (php)?

Comment: @c.k it is possible to use PHP to create the API. Depends on how complicated you want it, but the very least you can have the remote app  call your server with an API key and a service, maybe some variables, and your server would react and send back the proper data.

Comment: @Rasclatt, Do I need to put something on the header of my html pages so that session will work?

Comment: No you do a "stateless" session. You would do an api page that has nothing on it except returns data (preferably json). I can do a basic demonstration if you want. Don't take it as *the* way to do it, but I have used api's similar.

Comment: @Rasclatt, Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: For me it is easy to make a session in php-server side. But with client side it is hard for me.

Comment: So, let me just clarify to make sure we are on the same page: You want remote devices to be able to log into your webserver and simulate sessions (ie be able to get their own user info and such)?

Comment: @Rasclatt, Just like that. You may check my detailed question here and existing code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669015/display-user-info-upon-logging-in-using-php-session-hybrid-app

Comment: Sure, Thank you. I will check this out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need a host server that will authenticate and talk to your devices. Common protocols would be the use of `cURL` and `JSON` response:

**REMOTE DEVICE**

1) Your device, I will use another server because it's easy, will start a connection using cURL:

```
function cURL($variables = false)
    {
        $url = "http://www.example.com/";
        $query = (!empty($variables))? '?'.http_build_query($variables) : '';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url.$query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if(!empty($response))
            $data = json_decode($response,true);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

$login = cURL(array(
                'service'=>'login',
                'apikey'=>123123,
                'username'=>'whatever',
                'password'=>'whatever')
              );

print_r($login);
```

**API HOST SERVER**

2) Your server then will be listening for services. I am using `$_GET` but `$_POST` is better:

```
if(!empty($_GET['service'])) {
    switch($_GET['service']) {
        case('login'):
            logInUser($_GET);
    }
}
```

The `logInUser()` function would just do the normal login function except that it would set `timestamp`, `token`, `apikey`, and `username` in the database and return that via json on success:

```
//...authentication code here...//
if($valid) {
    // However you want to make a token
    $token = md5($usename.mt_rand(1000000,9999999).time());
    // Do code here to save the username, token, apikey, timestamp into database

    // This will then echo back the token on success to the device 
    die(json_encode(array('token'=>$token,'success'=>true)));
}
else {
    die(json_encode(array('token'=>'','success'=>'bad username/password')));
}
```

After this point, the device calls back to the host with the token in the query string as well as the apikey. It would also include a service and any variables that the service requires to send data back to the device. Every hit to the server triggers the server to look for an apikey, then service, then if service is not `login`, would require the token. It would query the database and check that all those things in the database are valid. If the token exists and the timestamp is recent enough (you can set the expiration time on that) then service runs. After service runs (or before complete), the `timestamp` value for the token is updated to current time.

Comment: Thank you for this. You give me an idea. I will work on my app base on the logic I got from your demonstration.